# generate .html files from the list of words?

Tags: html, text

I'm wondering, is there a possibility to generate somehow .html files from a list of words?

See an example on the attached picture.

Thanks!
[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFXgA.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it's possible to write code which outputs HTML.

Comment: Please could you explain what kind of code do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!! we can use file handling library to create file using the list of words.
I am attaching a python program below
lis=["file1", "file2"]
for x in lis:
    open(x+".html")

run this above program and get the output