# Create html files from a list

Tags: python, html, list

I am wondering if it is possible to create html files from a list.  For example, I want to create an html file for each letter of the alphabet.  Is it possible to create a list in notepad or excel such as:

- a
- b
- c
- d
- etc.

and then run a program or code that would output a bunch of files (a.html, a.html, c.html, and so on)

I'm pretty ignorant about programming and coding, so if there's a simple solution, I would greatly appreciate any help.  I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675157/generate-html-files-from-the-list-of-words) but I have no idea how to use the code.

Comment: What coding language are you trying to do this in, and what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? The very question you linked to gives you an example of how to do exactly what you're asking -- what specifically are you struggling with?

Comment: I think I was hoping there was a program that would do it.  I did not know exactly what Python was when I posted, I just knew it had to do with programming.  The extent of my "skills" is basic HTML and CSS.  I have since figured out what Python is, installed it, and attempted to make a few .py files from tutorials, but if they're working, I can't find the files on my computer.

Comment: @Snow please undo your edit where you pasted my answer into your question. It is clearer for future visitors if the question remains a question and the top answer contains the best solution. You can accept my answer to indicate to others that it solved your problem. Have a read of: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Marti157's answer gives you the bare bones of how to do it (after replacing `"some text"` with your `message`). It involves a clever trick where rather than listing out all the letters of the alphabet, you give the ASCI code for 'a', which is 97, and add `i`, a number that starts at 0 and goes up for every repetition of the loop.

So this shows you you don't actually need a list to do exactly what you set out to do. But a list could be useful in a number of ways, so let's generate one using the same trick @Marti157 used:

```
alphabet = [chr(97+i) for i in range(26)]
```

You can do it in one line! This is one of the cool things about Python. Of course, this is probably a dummy example and in the end you'll have a more specific list which you'll want to specify manually. Like so:

```
file_list = ["main", "about", "myhobbies", "catscatscats"]
```

Once you have a list, the loop that generates the files for you (using the `alphabet` list and your `message`) is:

```
for letter in alphabet:
    f = open(letter+".html", "w")
    f.write(message)
    f.close()
```

The next thing you'll want to do to really make this functional is vary the content of the html file according to the item in the list. For this, let's use '@' as a placeholder within your `message` text, that we'll later replace with a different letter of the alphabet for each file.

```
alphabet = [chr(97+i) for i in range(26)]
message = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is page @</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is @ Heading</h1>
<p>This is @ paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>"""

for letter in alphabet:
    f = open(letter+".html", "w")
    f.write(message.replace("@", letter))
    f.close()
```

Now w.html should read:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This is page w</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is w Heading</h1>
<p>This is w paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Hopefully this will get you excited about the possibilities for automating this kind of thing with Python!

### File management

If you are struggling to find the files generated, I'd first look in the directory your Python script is saved. Or, if you're typing it directly in terminal, you might want to check your working directory (quit Python first) using `pwd`. (I'm assuming it's a Unix terminal, ie. you're using a Mac.) Look into how to use `pwd` and `cd` (or their Windows equivalents) to get the files generated where you want them.

Of course the easiest thing would be to tell Python where to save things. [This](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter8/) should tell you everything you need to know.

### P.S.

Please tag your question with Python. It's what you've chosen to use, whether you realised it or not (and it's a good choice!), and it's what all the answers relate to.

Comment: I think I messed up using the alphabet as my example.  What I want is to create the file from a list of words haha.  While Googl'ing trying to figure it out is how I discovered I could add my base page template at the same time.  So, if I want to use a list of words, I use your file_list = ["main", "about", "myhobbies", "catscatscats"].  What do I replace for letter in alphabet:
    f = open(letter+".html", "w") with to make it go from the file_list?  Greatly appreciate the help, I've added Python to my "to learn" list!  Also added the tag, thank you so much!

Comment: Also, should that block of code to create the alphabet pages with the message.replace code take a long time to do it?  (Like over 20 minutes?)

Comment: Something is working!  I'll edit my post with the code since it won't work here.

Comment: Yes, use `file_list` instead of `alphabet`... and actually, `letter` is just an arbitrary name I've given to the item in the list I'm looping over. So you could even keep it as `letter`! Or, to be less confusing, change it to a better name like `filename`

Comment: And no, nothing this simple should take more than a second :/

Comment: I don't have the reputation to comment on your question, but @Snow, please undo the edit where you inserted my code solution in your question. In order for questions to be helpful to others down the line, they need to see your original question and the answer separately. You can accept my answer (click the tick to the left of it) to indicate to others that my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using python:

```
for i in range(26):
    f = open(chr(97+i)+".html", "w")
    f.write("Some text")
    f.close()
```

It should write a file with every letter in the alphabet.

Comment: but is it a valid HTML page?